# NPM version mismatch when using caret (^) or tilde (~)

Tags: node.js, npm, semantic-versioning

I have a main application with a `package.json`:

```
{
  name: "My App",
  "dependencies": {
    "@myGroup/someLib: "0.2.0"
    "@myGroup/common: "0.10.0" --> The version is fixed.
  }
}
```

Here is the `package.json` of my lib:

```
{
  name: "@myGroup/someLib",
  "dependencies": {
    "@myGroup/common: "^0.3.0" --> Notice the caret
  }
}
```

When doing a `npm install`, NPM will install 2 different versions, 0.3.0 and 0.10.0.

I'm expecting to have a single version installed given the caret. How can I achieve that? Is it the expected outcome?

Should I rather use `peerDependencies`?

Comment: `0.x` versions are treated differently; `0.3.0` -> `0.10.0` is effectively a major version change, because the public API is not considered stable in major version zero.

Comment: Ok. Good to known. Thanks !